# Normal load and long term fuel trim operating range for 2008 Toyota Matrix with 129,233 miles?

Tags: toyota, matrix, obd-ii, pid

When accelerating up an on ramp, are 90%+ engine loads and 10.90 long term fuel trim values within normal operating range for 2008 Toyota Matrix with 129,233 miles? [image: PIDs From Test Drive]

Edit: - added [full spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fWYId7QrPAT1vH_Z3xfxsK4Aj5cRZqH7lQ9KbnH0sx8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you having a drivability issue?

Comment: @Milison - This is used car that my daughter wants to buy. There are no driveability issues, no codes other than tire sensors, all monitors are complete, it's smog ready. The only caution was the learned LTFT value during acceleration up the ramp. Since total fuel trim is less than 25%, I'm not terribly concerned about a material mechanical issue; just be cautious.

Comment: I see a lot of good running vehicles in that fuel trim range.  Nothing that I'd be concerned about.